# SQL select products by tag_name

Tags: sql

I have a SQL database structured like so

Products:

```
-id
-name
```

Tags:

```
-tag_id
-tag_name
```

ProductTags:

```
-product_id
-tag_id
```

And I need to select all products that have tags associated with named like %partial_tag_name%

I understand I will have to do two joints but how should I make that request ?
Thanks

Edit: thanks to your response I could mannage to build the request like so:

```
        $results = Products::select(['product.*'])
            ->distinct()
            ->join('ProductTags', 'ProductTags.product_id', '=', products.id')
            ->join('tags', 'tags.tag_id', '=', 'ProductTags.tag_id')
            ->where('tags.tag_name', 'like',  "%{$query}%")
            ->get();
```

Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Do it in steps. Start with one join. Verify the result. Add another join. Verify result. Add WHERE clause with LIKE. Verify result.

Comment: Please understand that you are expected to make some sort of attempt to achieve your desired result before posting a question.  If you have already done so, please include your attempt in the question, along with the result and how it differs from your desired result.

Comment: I believe this is the answer: `SELECT DISTINCT
    Products.*
FROM
    Products
    LEFT JOIN ProductTags ON ProductTags.product_id = Products.id
    LEFT JOIN Tags ON Tags.tag_id = ProductTags.tag_id
WHERE
    Tags.tag_name LIKE '%partial_tag_name%'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Select p.name from Tags t 
JOIN ProductTags pt ON pt.tag_id = t.tag_id 
JOIN Products p on p.id = pt.product_id 
WHERE tag_name like %tag_name%;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.* FROM products p
JOIN product_tags pt ON pt.product_id = p.id
JOIN tags t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
WHERE t.name LIKE '%some_text%'
```